# Learn Python the Hard Way Exercise 39

Tags: python

I'm currently on LPTHW and I'm completely stuck on the first part of exercise 39 where you're making a dictionary. I currently have

```
states = [
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI'
]
```

Which as far as I can tell is exactly what the exercise has. However, every time I try to run the program I get a syntax error on line 2 (Oregon) with the arrow pointing at the colon. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You get a `SyntaxError` because your syntax is wrong. You are failing [Step 2](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/intro.html).

Comment: Note that Cyber's answer is correct but the .mobi version of this book uses square brackets, while the online version uses the correct curly brackets.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, you assumed incorrectly. He did not actually type it incorrectly, there *is* a mistake in the book (square brackets instead of curly brackets) in this section, at least in the 3rd edition there is.

Comment: @SamAndrew81 another one on the pile for https://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints, I guess

Answer (score 6):

A dictionary would be this

```
states = {
    'Oregon': 'OR',
    'Florida': 'FL',
    'California': 'CA',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'Michigan': 'MI'
}
```

Note the `{}`. When you use `[]` you are making a list, and it (correctly) does not know what to do with the `:` character.

Comment: The book uses square brackets, hence the confusion on this. That's also how I got here.